# ¿como resto de una seleccion random al que salio sorteado para hacer una nuevo random hasta que solo quede 1?

Tags: python

se supone que pongo 4 nombres y de ellos ya saque el sorteo de quien sera el manager_student, pero ahora de los que quedaron en la lista y no fueron seleccionados, quiero sacar otro nombre para que sea el secretary_student y luego el trasurer_student y el que quede en la lista sin ser sorteado, sera el worker_student

aqui les mando mi codigo hasta ahora. Gxs por su apoyo!!

```
#This is a students selector. When you need a random selection of the students to assign the role each one has to follow.
#The avaiable roles are: manager, secretary, treasurer, worker. Type the names of the 4 students and this system will tell you wich role has to play in the organization.
import random

print("Welcome to the Role Assign App!\n")

students = input(print("Please type the name of the students you want to assign:\n")).lower()
names = students.split(", ")
students_number = len(names)
random_student = random.randint(0, students_number -1)
manager_student = names[random_student]
print(f"The manager of the activity will be: {manager_student}, congratulations!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución más general, por si necesitas hacerlo para N nombres, podría ser la siguiente:

```
>>> # Voy a usar las letras del alfabeto como si fueran nombres
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> names = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
>>> print(names)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> # Obtengo un estudiante
>>> random_student = random.choice(names)
>>> random_student
'P'
>>> # Obtengo el índice del estudiante elegido
>>> index = names.index(random_student)
>>> names[index]
'P'
>>> # Lo saco de la lista
>>> names.pop(index)
>>> # Adiós alumno 'P'
>>> names
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

De esta forma es imposible obtener el mismo resultado si usas `random.choice` la próxima vez. Tal vez el algoritmo se pueda mejorar dado que la complejidad de `list.index` es O(n), es decir, depende del tamaño de la lista.

Esto tranquilamente lo puedes usar en una función:

```
def select_random_item(list):
    if not list:
        print('Lista vacía')
        return None
    item = random.choice(list)
    index = list.index(item)
    list.pop(index)
    return item
```

**OJO**: La función toma la lista como parámetro y la modifica, recuerda que las listas son pasadas por referencia, no por valor. Esto quiere decir que si modificas la lista dentro de la función, la lista original se verá afectada. Observa:

```
>>> def select_random_item(list):
...     if not list:
...         print('Lista vacía')
...         return None
...     item = random.choice(list)
...     index = list.index(item)
...     list.pop(index)
...     return item
... 
>>> students = ['Cesar', 'Juan', 'JASolis']
>>> select_random_item(students)
'JASolis'
>>> select_random_item(students)
'Juan'
>>> select_random_item(students)
'Cesar'
>>> select_random_item(students)
Lista vacía
>>> select_random_item(students)
Lista vacía
>>> students
[]
```

Si quieres que la función se detenga cuando quede un elemento, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
>>> def select_random_item(list, min_length=2):
...     if len(list) < min_length:
...         return None
...     item = random.choice(list)
...     index = list.index(item)
...     list.pop(index)
...     return item
... 
>>> students = ['Cesar', 'Juan', 'JASolis']
>>> select_random_item(students)
'JASolis'
>>> select_random_item(students)
'Juan'
>>> select_random_item(students)  # None
>>> select_random_item(students)  # None
>>> select_random_item(students)  # None
>>> students
['Cesar']
```

¿Quién se lleva el premio?

```
>>> students = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
>>> students
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> while select_random_item(students):
...   pass
... 
>>> students  # <- ganador
['K']
```

O algo más pythonico:

```
>>> students = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
>>>  [select_random_item(students) for i in range(len(students))]
>>> students
['Q']
```

Comment: Caray César, creo que es la explicación mas extensa que alguien me haya hecho sobre un tema, te agradezco tu paciencia!!

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: Con esto no respondo directamente el enunciado de tu pregunta, sino que te ofrezco un enfoque alternativo para abordar tu problema*

. . .

Considerando que tienes una lista con los nombres (`names`), puedes hacer uso de una función muy útil del módulo `random`, la cual te permite mezclar el orden de los elementos internos de esa lista. Esta función se llama `shuffle()`.

Además, aprovechando la característica de asignación múltiple que nos permite realizar Python, podemos tener el código de una manera muy sucinta, tal como se muestra a continuación:

```
import random


names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'FizzBuzz']    # En tu caso, esta lista la creas a partir del input del usuario
random.shuffle(names)
manager, secretary, treasurer, worker = names
```

Comment: caray, muchas gracias... interesante punto de vista, hare las pruebas. :)